# Truncated string usability

Tags: website-design, layout, information-architecture

I am faced with a tricky situation in a data-driven application. I have really long names and a short field for them only available.

My idea was to use css-ellipsis to cut the length to appropriate one and then add a title attribute to show the full name. But this might be too obscure for users to find.

I am wondering how to solve this?

Comment: The solution is easy. Design the UI to accommodate the actual data that it is presenting.

Answer (score 3):

What @JonW is saying is **key** here. You should always have your content in mind when designing a UI, therefore if the names are long, you most definitely should have a long field instead of a short one to accommodate them.

That being said, and assuming you have already thought about this and your current situation impedes you from doing so, I found that the use of CSS ellipsis along with some tooltip functionality seem to do the trick quite well, and users found it to be intuitive and helpful.